# Xamarin.Android : Deserialize a file in ApplicationData?

Tags: android, xamarin, serialization, xamarin.android

I'm storing user data in ApplicationData folder. Its path is obtained with :

```
userDataPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "userData");
```

This variable is equal to `/data/user/0/APPNAME/files/.config/userData`.

Each time I rebuild the project, if I delete the userData file with `File.Delete(userDataPath)`, I can successfully create the file, write and read to it several times. I can indeed check the created file in `/data/data/APPNAME/files/.config/userData`.
I check in `/data/data/.../.config/userData` and not in `/data/user/.../.config/userData` because apparently the latter is a symlink to the former, so it should be equivalent ? Moreother I don't have access to `/data/user/.../.config/userData`.

The problem is that if I rebuild the app without deleting the file, I got an unhandled exception at the following Deserialization (which worked fine before) :

```
  if (File.Exists(userDataPath))
            {
                Stream reader = new FileStream(userDataPath, FileMode.Open); 
                Console.WriteLine(userDataPath);
                userData = (UserData)serializer.Deserialize(reader); // ERROR HERE
                reader.Close();
            }
```

It is very strange because the file located at `/data/data/APPNAME/files/.config/userData` does not exist but since `File.Exists(userDataPath)` is `true`, the file located at `/data/user/0/APPNAME/files/.config/userData` does exist.

So how can this be explained and is this the correct way to store data in ApplicationData folder ?

Comment: have you tried catching the exception so you can see what the actual cause is?

Comment: Nothing more than `There is an error in XML document`. The only difference before and after rebuild, is that the file has been deleted from `/data/data/APPNAME/files/.config/` but apparently not from `/data/user/0/APPNAME/files/.config/userData`.

Comment: have you examined the document for errors?  Have you tried using a different SpecialFolder?

Comment: Prior to being deleted in `/data/data/APPNAME/files/.config/` during the rebuild, the XML file has indeed proper syntax. 
I tried your suggestion of using another SpecialFolder (LocalApplicationData) and for some reason the problem does not occur anymore. This time `File.Exists(userDataPath)` returns `false` so file has been properly deleted from `/data/user/.../.local/share` during rebuild. I don't understand the role of `/data/data/.../.local/share` and its link with `/data/user/.../.local/share` because the former remains occasionnally empty even after file is created.

Comment: Can you please share us the stacktrace?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : I switched back to ApplicationData and am now unable to reproduce the exception. As soon as this reproduces, I'll update this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to another SpecialFolder (LocalApplicationData), I can't reproduce the unhandeld exception anymore (even when switching back to ApplicationData).

I'll keep this post updated if it ever happens again.